# How to add json data to mat options values in angular 14

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular14

Trying to change the mat options checkbox value by json data to but not able to change.I have three buttons, Each button have josn data file.If i click  the New Data 1 button i want to set the that value for selectOptions, Same for others. How to do it and How to resolve this issue.

app.component.ts:

```
addData(url) {
     this.httpClient.get<any>(url).subscribe((data) => { 
     this.selectOptions = data;
  });
  }
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kunrso?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ngOnInit()`, you should use `ngOnChanges` that will capture the latest value of `selectedOptions` to `mauto.component.ts`.

Inside the `ngOnChanges()`, you need to patch the value of `selectControl`, so that `filteredData` is updated correctly, since your dropdown render's the checkbox options from `filteredData`, not from `rawData`. Also, need to reset `selectData` to remove all the chips.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

    if (changes.data && changes.data.currentValue) {
      this.rawData = [];
      console.log(changes.data.currentValue)
      this.data.forEach((item: string) => {
        this.rawData.push({ item, selected: false });
      });

      this.selectData = [];
      this.selectControl.setValue(this.rawData)
      console.log(this.selectControl)
    }
 
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sofvvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.html)

Comment: New SO : 73234592

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, have posted an answer, that one was easy to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from the top to bottom:

1. In your links in the template you had "grpX.josn" - a simple typo, but it would impossible to fetch data even if it was hosted properly.
2. The "assets" should be placed directly under the "app" directory, not in the "app" subdirectory. Hence, they will not be reachable by a http call. Alternatively, you can add your path to the "assets" array in the `angular.json`
3. Once you sort out the above two, you should get a proper response from your  http get calls. But note that your `MautoComponent` does not listen to changes in your input - you use it once during `ngOnInit` and then it's not re-used later on. Either re-work your component to rely on the `@Input() data` to display the items, or implement `OnChange` interface and handle the your logic there.

Comment: Now getting the data but how to set the value using onchange. Please update your changes in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kunrso?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html